# Export an array to another file after I generate it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file-sharing, module.exports

So essentially I have three files: main.js, helper.js, & mapLibrary.js

Main.js is an api call generator that creates an array of objects using helper methods in helper.js.
I want to export the array once its created to mapLibrary.js.

The problem is that once I module.export the array it results as undefined. I believe this is because module.exports is exporting it at the start of the file before it's fully populated with objects. I've tried exporting it inside of an end flag for the generation but that doesn't work either.

One solution is to use async promises/callbacks but that would potentially further convolute my code and I would just like to transfer this variable array files in a simple way rather than refactor all my existing code. Any ideas?

Main.js

```
//API Call + generation logic
if(endFlag)  
module.exports = objectArray;
//module.exports = new getObjectArray(); //Also tried exporting the function but not working, rather export variable
```

mapLibrary.js

```
    const objectArray = require('./main')
    console.log(objectArray) //Empty or only has one object
```

Sorry for the vagueness, but any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to export a result of an asynchronous call? Seems like that is not going to work. Hard to guess with the minimal amount of code/info given.

Comment: how about you just make the `main.js` into the async function that does the api call, then send the export as *that* function(making sure the function returns `objectArray` of course) and then on the other side, you can just `let api_call=require('./main');let objArr=await api_call();console.log(objArr)`?

Comment: side note, async operator would be for async function.. so running it in an async block should avoid errors